# How to remove jax-ws webservice from project after it's been created

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, jax-ws

In Eclipse I created a dynamic web project, wrote a POJO class and exposed it as a SOAP webservice. After that a whole bunch of files and other directories got created:

[image]

Just a few examples of what I'm talking about. What I want to know now is, how do I go about actually removing the generated "webservice stuff" and basically return to my project that only contains the original POJO class I created. So how do I *remove* a generated webservice, but not the class that it was generated from?

My first instinct was to just delete anything and everything that sounds like it has something to do with webservices. However I'm sure that's not the way to do it.

Comment: If the above isn't possible, is it possible to 'refresh' the generated wsdl files? My source classes have since gotten new methods etc and the wsdls aren't reflecting those changes..

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Maven project simple type **mvn clean** command on your project which will remove your generated code.

Comment: Alas.. it's not a maven project.